# specifying values in enum in XSD

Tags: c#, xsd

I have defined a enum as below in the XSD file

```
 <xs:simpleType name="PaperSizes">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="NUMBERS"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="PICTURE"></xs:enumeration>
      <xs:enumeration value="RTF"></xs:enumeration>
    </xs:restriction>
```

I need to override the detault values assigned by the compiler. ie:- for NUMBERS the default value will be 0. I  need the value 2 for it.

What changes i need to make?

Thanks.

Comment: I think the best you can do, and only if your numeric values are sequential and start at 0, is reorder the entries in the XSD. Otherwise, you'll need to do some translation from XSD enums to the numeric values you want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot set a different default for each of the values in a collection. You can set one default value for any xsd simple type with the "default" keyword.

So if you want to set a default value in your example above you could do something like:

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element default="PICTURE" name="PaperSizes">
          <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
              <xs:enumeration value="NUMBERS" />
              <xs:enumeration value="PICTURE" />
              <xs:enumeration value="RTF" />
            </xs:restriction>
          </xs:simpleType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

I hope this helps.